# How to encrypt (and decrypt) data with pycrypto and RSA?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, rsa, pycrypto

I've been trying to encrypt data in Python with RSA in pycrypto.  I've tried to follow the instructions here: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-and-cryptography-with-pycrypto/ but here's what comes out when I call `enc_data = public_key.encrypt('abcdefgh', 32)`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
  enc_data = public_key.encrypt('abcdefgh', 32)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 150, in encrypt
    return pubkey.pubkey.encrypt(self, plaintext, K)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py", line 75, in encrypt
    ciphertext=self._encrypt(plaintext, K)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 224, in _encrypt
    return (self.key._encrypt(c),)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py", line 65, in _encrypt
    return pow(m, self.e, self.n)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for pow(): 'str', 'int', 'int'
```

Thanks in advance for any advice regarding this issue.

Comment: Why are you using RSA to encrypt data?

Comment: Please don't use textbook (unpadded) RSA, because it is very insecure. Have a look at [`Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP-module.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `encrypt` method:

> `plaintext` (byte string or long) - The piece of data to encrypt with RSA. It may not be numerically larger than the RSA module (n).

Your data is not a byte string or long. If you want to input text then you first need to use a character encoding such as UTF-8 for input.

Note that "plaintext" is just the input for the cryptographic primitives. All modern ciphers operate on bytes. Historically the input may have been actual text, but not anymore.

---

Also note that:

> Attention: this function performs the plain, primitive RSA encryption (textbook). In real applications, you always need to use proper cryptographic padding, and you should not directly encrypt data with this method. Failure to do so may lead to security vulnerabilities. It is recommended to use modules `Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP` or `Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5` instead.

For these functions it is also required to convert your text to byte arrays.

Comment: PKCS1_v1_5 is used for signing, not for key generation. From manual: "key (RSA key object) - The key to use to sign or verify the message. This is a Crypto.PublicKey.RSA object. Signing is only possible if key is a private RSA key.
"

Comment: This is about encryption, not key generation. Reread Q & A, not one word about key generation.